# How to end this infinite loop

Tags: python, list, sorting, loops, infinite

I have to sort a user inputed list from lowest to highest without . sort, but when I try to replace two values to put them in order I find myself in an infinite loop

```
list = input('Enter list of numbers separated by a space: ').split()
list = [int(b) for b in list]

def list_sort(list):
    while list:
        a = list[0]         # random number in list
        for x in list:      # to check every number in the list
            if x < a:       # find if the new number is less than original
                c, d = list.index(x), list.index(a)
                list[d], list[c] = list[c], list[d] 


print(list_sort(list))
```

Comment: since you never remove any elements from the list I dont know how you are expecting to exit the `while list` method (also you shouldnt name variables `list` or other builtin constructs) ... it appears you are trying to implement bubble sort ... there are many solutions available online for this

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your while loop to run as long as list is True, which in your code is always going to be true. What you want to do instead is set up a condition inside your while loop to break out of your loop with a `break` statement.

```
while True: 
 if some_break_condition_met:
     break
 else:
     # do logic
```

Also, list is used in python to create a list, so I strongly suggest not using list as your variable, maybe change it to lst or my_list. Using list could cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = input('Enter list of numbers separated by a space: ').split(' ')
list = [int(b) for b in list]

def list_sort(list):
    updated = True
    while updated:
        updated = False
        for orig_index in range(0, len(list)):
            for check_index in range(orig_index, len(list)):      
                if list[check_index] < list[orig_index]:      
                    list[orig_index], list[check_index] = list[check_index], list[orig_index]
                    updated = True


print(list_sort(list))
```